# Whenever I use developer tool and resize it my website start shrinking

Tags: css, browser, firefox-developer-tools

Whenever I try to to use developer options in browser my website automatically starts shrinking

[image: image of a website]

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: A side note, you probably want "DOCTYPE" instead of "DOCKTYPE".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is the expected behavior. There is an option to open developer tools in a separate window in most browsers (that can be found in the top-right corner of the developer tools panel in your screenshot).